# Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Write_To_Console_dr' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Tags: c#

I am running the below in the same class, not sure why the Write_To_Console_dr can't be found.

```
public Int16 Write_To_Console_dr(string ConsoleCmd)
{
    this.textBoxConsole.AppendText(ConsoleCmd + "\n" );
    this.textBoxConsole.AppendText( "Tena_Console>");
    using (StreamWriter MySw = File.AppendText(Globals.LogFileName))
    {
        MySw.WriteLine(ConsoleCmd, " \n");
    }
    return 1;
}

public static Int16 Write_To_Console(string ConsoleCmd)
{
    Write_To_Console_dr Winst = new Write_To_Console_dr();
    Winst(ConsoleCmd);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest reading some `Free OnLine C# Basic Tutorials`
[Understanding Classes, Methods, and Properties in C#](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_syntax/anandctutorials/article.php/c5829/Understanding-Classes-Methods-and-Properties-in-C.htm)

Comment: Code you've provided does not reproduce the error. Please make sure to post [MCVE].

Answer (score 2):

You're initializing a method as if it were a class.

```
Write_To_Console_dr Winst = new Write_To_Console_dr();
```

Instead you should write:

```
public static Int16 Write_To_Console(string ConsoleCmd)
{
    Write_To_Console_dr(ConsoleCmd);
    return 1;
}
```

Also, your `Write_To_Console_dr` method may need to be `static` as well depending upon how you've written your code.

```
public static Int16 Write_To_Console_dr(string ConsoleCmd)
```

If your method is within a class, it would be:

```
public static Int16 Write_To_Console(string ConsoleCmd)
{
    MyClass cls = new MyClass(); // Where this is your class' name.
    cls.Write_To_Console_dr(ConsoleCmd);
    return 1;
}
```

But, as other's stated in the comments above, I think you need to read a bit about object oriented design and some tutorials on C#. Good luck!

Comment: If I am doing so I am geting  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'FormMain.Write_To_Console_dr(string)' TSDK C:\Users\Administrator\Box Sync\Tena\TSDK\Rev_0\TSDK\TSDK\Form1.cs 204

Comment: I tried to make Write_To_Console_dr static but had hard time writing into a textbox. in the textBoxConsole.AppendText(ConsoleCmd + "\n" );

Comment: I was able to compile as described above with cls.Write_To_Console_dr but now I don't see the text in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a function as a class

you should be calling it like this instead of

```
Write_To_Console_dr Winst = new Write_To_Console_dr();
```

it should be

```
int retVal = Write_To_Console(ConsoleCmd);
```

**EDIT**

And a better way to write the code for

```
this.textBoxConsole.AppendText(ConsoleCmd + "\n" );
this.textBoxConsole.AppendText( "Tena_Console>");
```

Would be

```
textBoxConsole.Text =  textBoxConsole.Text + ConsoleCmd + "\n" + "Tena_Console>";
```

Finally you should have the code like this

```
public Int16 Write_To_Console_dr(string ConsoleCmd)
{
    textBoxConsole.Text =  textBoxConsole.Text + ConsoleCmd + "\n" + "Tena_Console>";
    using(StreamWriter MySw = File.AppendText("akjsdh"))
    {
        MySw.WriteLine(ConsoleCmd, " \n");
    }
    return 1;
}

public Int16 Write_To_Console(string ConsoleCmd)
{
    int retVal =  Write_To_Console_dr(ConsoleCmd);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: It is not a console application, it is a form application that I added a textbox to use it as a console.

Comment: If I am doing so I am getting An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Comment: I tried to make Write_To_Console_dr static but had hard time writing into a textbox. in the textBoxConsole.AppendText(ConsoleCmd + "\n" ); –

Comment: I need to be able to access Write_To_Console from many locations in the code, so I guess it should be static.

Comment: Static is not meant to be called from many location or one. It is meant to called at some point between when the program starts and the class is instantiated.

Comment: I tried the int retVal =  Write_To_Console_dr(ConsoleCmd); but getting   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'FormMain.Write_To_Console_dr(string)' TSDK C:\Users\Administrator\Box Sync\Tena\TSDK\Rev_0\TSDK\TSDK\Form1.cs 209

Comment: sir @Sharon you need to remove `static` keyword than only it would get solved

Comment: If I remove the static, how should I call this methods from other locations in the code?

Comment: from other location you can create the object of `CurrentClass` than from that `ObjCurrentClass.Write_To_Console("SomeString");` can be called.

Comment: As soon as I create a new object the text will not go into the textbox since it is a new instance, correct me if I am wrong. I am just trying to send text into a text box from many locations in the code.